# cvs version number on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I have been using CVS in my eclipse project, till yesterday I was able to see version number of my java files in eclipse but from today on wards am not able to see version numbers of java files I am not getting how this happen and tried all possible options but cant find solution, so if anyone have idea about it, then please let me know.

Comment: When you right-click on files, is Eclipse still aware that the project is under the control of CVS?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't have problem with CVS connection I have problem with only versions of file not showing, I found solution for this Go Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Label Decorations under this CVS checkbox and maven checkbox is unchecked. Checked this 2 check boxes.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake the option comes under  Go Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Appearances -> Label Decorations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply, but I don't have problem with CVS connection I have problem with only versions of file not showing, I found solution for this Go Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Label Decorations under this CVS checkbox and maven checkbox is unchecked. Checked this 2 check boxes.